# Attempted to publish project. Can't run it at all now

Tags: visual-studio-2013, publish

I've been working on a C# (WinForms) Project on Visual Studio 2013 for a while and (mostly out of curiosity), I wanted to test the `Build>Publish` option. It failed and I got the following message:

`An error occurred while signing: SignTool.exe not found.`

However, the worst thing is that now clicking the `Start` button so that I can simply run my program gives me back the same error (I've never seen that error before!). What happened and how can I run my program?

Comment: `SignTool` is part of the build toolchain, and the fact that it is not found makes me suspect something is wrong with your installation of VS.  Repair the installation from "Programs and Features".

Comment: Okay, just finished the repair process. Everything seems to be working just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SignTool is part of the build toolchain, and the fact that it is not found makes me suspect something is wrong with your installation of VS.

Repair the installation from "Programs and Features".